# Cartthrob DB size

Tags: cartthrob

My EE+carttrob DB size is over 100MB, mostly because of the exp_cartthrob_cart and  exp_cartthrob_sessions tables. Can these be flushed/cleaned up at some point or better not to touch these? (sorry, I'm a total CB noob).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you state, all sessions and carts will be cleared if you clean those tables.

Depending on how long your sessions run, some visitors will lose their cart content.

Both tables have timestamp columns so you could choose to only clear the old ones.

Bart